# Testing My model mapper with spock and all test passes

Tags: java, testing, groovy, spock

Hello I have a problem with spock groovy testing. I need to write a Unit test for my model mapper, but always my test passes ok even I want to write wrong:
This is My model mapper:

```
public class ModelMapper {
    public ConferenceRoomDto fromConferenceRoomToConferenceRoomDto(ConferenceRoom conferenceRoom) {
        return conferenceRoom == null ? null : ConferenceRoomDto.builder()
                .roomName(conferenceRoom.getRoomName())
                .description(conferenceRoom.getDescription())
                .projector(conferenceRoom.getProjector())
                .phoneNumber(conferenceRoom.getPhoneNumber())
                .numberOfSeats(conferenceRoom.getNumberOfSeats())
                .build();
```

And this is My test:

```
given:
    ConferenceRoom conferenceRoom1 = ConferenceRoom.builder()
            .roomName("r")
            .projector(true)
            .description("d")
            .phoneNumber("23")
            .build()
    when:
    modelMapper.fromConferenceRoomToConferenceRoomDto(conferenceRoom1)
    then:
    ConferenceRoomDto conferenceRoomDto1 = ConferenceRoomDto.builder()
            .build()
}
```

This tets should fail because I give values to my conference room and I expect dto without values but all test pass ok.

Comment: Is there any assertion in your test?

Comment: No I use spock - I read there is not assertion But I think i resolve problem: I change body when and then and it's help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - so there are two problems with you test here.

1. `=` means assignment. To check for equality you need to use `==` on the last line of your test. This is not a Spock-specific thing - it's a general rule that applies in every programming language I've come across:

   - `a = b` means assign the value `b` to the variable `a`.
   - `a == b` means 'true' if `a` and `b` are in some way 'equal', 'false' otherwise.

   Spock expects code in a `then` block to end in an expression that can be evaluated as `true` (indicating the test passed) or `false`.
2. Your last line, even if it used the right `==` operator, is not actually comparing your expected value with the value returned by the previous line. I believe what you're looking for is:

   ```
   when:
   def result = modelMapper.fromConferenceRoomToConferenceRoomDto(conferenceRoom1)
   then:
   result == ConferenceRoomDto.builder().build()
   ```

   In Spock, I believe a more idiomatic way of expressing this would simply be:

   ```
   expect:
   modelMapper.fromConferenceRoomToConferenceRoomDto(conferenceRoom1)
       == ConferenceRoomDto.builder().build()
   ```

To reiterate, neither of these 2 problems are related to your use of Spock. You would have the same problem in any test framework or programming language, or even outside of testing.

Answer (score 0):

You are not testing anything in your example because `ConferenceRoomDto conferenceRoomDto1 = ConferenceRoomDto.builder().build()` is only assignment not the test. This is the reason why the test always pass.

Change your test on this for example:

```
def 'DTO is mapped from bean'() {
    given:
    ConferenceRoom conferenceRoom1 = ConferenceRoom.builder()
            .roomName("r")
            .projector(true)
            .description("d")
            .phoneNumber("23")
            .build()
    when:
    ConferenceRoomDto dto = modelMapper.fromConferenceRoomToConferenceRoomDto(conferenceRoom1)

    then:
    dto.roomName == 'r'
    dto.projector
    dto.description == 'd'
    dto.phoneNumber == '23'
}
```

In the `then` section are now 4 asserts which do the tests. For example that `roomName` value is equal to `'r'`.